# setTimeOut didn't work in $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I used the `setTimeOut()` in the `document.ready` function, it didn't work.

Here's the code I've used:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function abc{
    alert('Hi');
  }
  setTimeOut (abc, 2000);                    
});
```

What did I miss?

Thank you :)

Comment: Function name are case sensitive :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: Don't you use your browser console? The error should be obvious ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is spelt `setTimeout` (lowercase "o")

Also you can and should be able to find issues like these yourself. The only magic part that you need to know is that browsers tend to "swallow" exceptions thrown inside DOM and AJAX event handlers. So there is actually an exception thrown in your code. You can however easily deduce that by adding more `alert()` or `console.log()` statements on every line.

Comment: Thanks guys :)

The problem was with that capital letter "O". Also, I forgot to put the "()" braces after the function name while declaring it.

I'm using Google Chrome. I didn't tried checking the Javascript console, until you guys mentioned it here. :)
It's situated at the `Wrench button --> Tools --> Javascript Console`
I was able to see the errors there. :)

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + J ... handy shortcut for console.

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut too :)

Comment: You can also use F12 to see the console/developer tools.

Comment: @TryingToImprove I am surprised your edit was approved. The "deduce" was clearly the intended word here.

Comment: I have never heard that word before, so thought it was a typo. Sorry.. :-)

Comment: Was setTimeout spelled differently in the past? Currently, it is `spelled 'setTimeout'`. (spelt is in past tense)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the () on the function.

You need to do

```
function abc(){
    alert("Y");
}
```

or define functinon like this

```
var abc = function(){
    alert("Y")
}
```

Comment: Yes. Actually it was a dummy function that I have created for testing. So, instead of posting the actual function, I just posted the dummy function. But forgot to include the braces in it. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function abc(){
    alert('Hi');
  };
  setTimeout(abc, 2000);

});
```

Your original code had the wrong case for `setTimeout` also, you were missing the parentheses from your function call `function abc(){`

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/QQLjb/

Answer (score 2):

Try setTimeout() instead of setTimeOut()

Answer (score -1):

If you try to call abc function in every 2 seconds ;

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    abc();
 });

 function abc(){
   alert('Hi');
   setTimeout(abc, 2000);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks... :)
But I think, to call it repeatedly, we have to use the setInterval() function instead of setTimeout(). The setTimeout() will fire once after the specified time, but in the case of setInterval() it would repeat it for the specified time.

Correct me if I'm wrong.